# Error while loading images in a ListView through JSON

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I want to load both data and images in ListView but getting errors.

**FoodView.java**

```
public class FoodView extends ListActivity 
{
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

            private static String url_all_products = "http://ambrogroup.com/app/index/file/food";

            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
            private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
            private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
            private static final String TAG_IMG = "img";
            private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
            private static final String TAG_DESTINATION = "destination";

            JSONArray products = null;
            ListView lv;
            LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;

            private String[] str;



            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();        
                new LoadAllProducts().execute();                                
                lv = getListView();                                 

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {           
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                    {
                        /*
                        String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
                        String pname = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditProductActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                        */
                    }
                });
            }


            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
            {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == 100) 
                {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }

            class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
            {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute()
                {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FoodView.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading list. Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
                    Log.d("Gellting all the list : ", json.toString());

                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) 
                        {
                            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);
                            str = new String[products.length()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) 
                            {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                                String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                                String destination = c.getString(TAG_DESTINATION);
                                String img = c.getString(TAG_IMG);

                                str[i] = img;

                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                                map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                                map.put(TAG_DESTINATION, destination);
                                map.put(TAG_IMG, img);

                                productsList.add(map);
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {

                        /*  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i); */
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
                {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                                ListView list;
                                LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter;
                                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);    
                                adapter=new LazyImageLoadAdapter(FoodView.this, str,productsList);
                                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });

                }

            }
}
```

**LazyImageLoaderAdapter.java**

```
package com.ambrogroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

//Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener 
public class LazyImageLoadAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] iImage,iID,iName,iPrice,iDestination;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pList;
    private static final String TAG_PID="pid",TAG_NAME="name",TAG_DESTINATION="destination",TAG_PRICE="price";

    public LazyImageLoadAdapter(Activity a, String[] sImage, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList) {
        activity = a;
        iImage=sImage;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        pList = productsList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return iImage.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView vImage;
        public TextView  tName;
        public TextView  tPrice;
        public TextView  tDestination;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.tPrice=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.tDestination=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.destination);
            holder.vImage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.img);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        holder.tName.setText("Company"+position);
        holder.tPrice.setText("company description "+position);
        ImageView image = holder.vImage;

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(iImage[position], image);



        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
    private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
        private int mPosition;

       OnItemClickListener(int position){
             mPosition = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //FoodView sct = (FoodView)activity;
            //sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
        }               
    }   
}
```

Following error Iam facing

**Logcat Error**

```
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): Process: com.ambrogroup, PID: 4814
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.ambrogroup.FoodView$LoadAllProducts$1.run(FoodView.java:160)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4713)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.ambrogroup.FoodView$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(FoodView.java:152)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.ambrogroup.FoodView$LoadAllProducts.onPostExecute(FoodView.java:1)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-25 10:28:28.498: E/AndroidRuntime(4814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on Line 160 of FoodView.java ?

Comment: list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: try `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) already have `ListView` bundled with it, so this piece of code in your `Runnable` doesn't make sense:

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
```

You get `NPE` because after that string `list` is `null` - nothing is found. I suggest you to use the following code:

```
LazyImageLoadAdapter adapter = new LazyImageLoadAdapter(FoodView.this, str,productsList);
getListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also `onPostExecute`is always invoked on the UI thread, there is no need to use `runOnUiThread`

Comment: thank you so much sir.. I had taken 1 week to do this image loading in list view... thanks a lot..

Comment: one more thing i want to ask that i have data also to show.. it is only showing images.. i want to show data also that is stored in HASH MAP ARRAY.. how to manipulate it..??

Comment: @RaghvendraDwivedi the question is unclear. Are you asking how to traverse HashMap?

Comment: I am asking that Iam sending productsList through LazyImageLoadAdapter(FoodView.this, str,productsList). So how can I show data of productsList

Comment: @RaghvendraDwivedi at the `getView` method of `Adapter` you have `position` parameter. Just use it to get the needed `HashMap` via `pList.get(position)`

Comment: I did this :-   holder.tName.setTag(pList.get(position));
         holder.tPrice.setTag(pList.get(position));
         holder.tDestination.setTag(pList.get(position));
        But not worked..

Comment: @RaghvendraDwivedi you are doing it in a wrong way, please take a look here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the listview and the adpater in the FoodView class and set it to the listview onCreate?

Comment: how it could be possible and if it is then please give me the code or reference.